# How do i pass an extra parameter to server using jqgrid and http method POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm doing something like the guy in this post: [is there a way to programatically set a filter in jquery jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311929/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-set-a-filter-in-jquery-jqgrid)

I'm using http method POST to to get data from my MVC2 project and i saw that you can add a parameter using GET doing like this:

```
You can modify the url that jqGrid calls, and add the filter option to the querystring, then handle it on the server side.

    $(link).click(function(){

    $(".mygrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"server.php?useMyFilter=1"})
    });
```

How can i add a extra filter parameter using POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both `GET` *and* `POST` you can set `postData`:

```
$(".mygrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',
{
     url:"server.php",
     postData: {
         useMyFilter: 1
     }
});
```

Note that your call to `jqGrid()` is missing a `;`