# jqGrid Force filter trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have jqGrid 4.1.2 and Iam trying to force filters to be triggered on $(document).ready(

What I want to achieve is to fill one of filtering fields with values and "press enter" so jqGrid would filter it out.

I have passed values to the page by GET, propagated the filter field value like this:

```
         var filteritem = document.getElementById("gs_fieldToBeFilteredID");
         filteritem.value = "MY filter value";
```

It causes that filter field is filled with "My filter value". But now Iam trying to trigger "enter press" on the end of the document like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#myGrid")[0].triggerToolbar();
}
);
```

I have tried also

```
 jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

with NO effect. I also put above code in jQGrid  loadComplete event with NO effect either.
Filter is filled but I "can't" force it to trigger filtering ... any ideas ?!

I would apprecieate any help.
Best regards

Comment: I have found that adding some delay causes that this works ok:
        var xxx = jQuery("#list2_<%= this.ClientID %>");
        alert("DELAY");
        xxx.jqGrid("filterToolbar");
        $("#list2_<%= this.ClientID %>")[0].triggerToolbar();

but adding delay it's not an option

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFilter.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311929/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-set-a-filter-in-jquery-jqgrid) is what you need.

After you set `value` on the `<input>` element you could trigger `change` filter and then use

```
$(filteritem).focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', charCode : 13 });
```

Depend on where you trigger the `keypress` event you could need to do this in *separate* thread. So it could be that you will need to do this in the `setTimeout` like I did it in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You Should be able to add post data to the grid, that is what you want so you don't need to retrigger the grid to reload. It will get it within the inital request.

Here is the full article: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:post_data_module

Ive done it with "before request" event, setting up an function that adds the data that you want.

```
function jqGridBeforeRequest()
{
   $(this).appendPostData(<JSON/object data here>);
}
```